# asp.net vnext. mvc 6. Implement simple own authorization

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-core

I am writing simple REST service for leaning vNext and new MVC. I want to understand how to create a simple OWIN authorization with custom logic. 
For example, imagine that a service has just a simple in-memory list of tokens and I want to check that a request contains token that exist in that list.

If I understood properly, I just need to override AuthorizeAttribute class, but I cannot find how to do this in the right way.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
    }
}
```

If I misunderstood this, could you please explain what classes I need to use and can I do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
public class AuthorizeClass: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Session["token"] == null || context.HttpContext.Session["user"] == null)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/login");
            }
            await next();
        }

    }
```